# How to update an instance value with another document

Tags: xslt-2.0, xforms, xsltforms

We are using XSLTForms and XSLT to display a page.
I have an instance on a page whose value is set as a document.

```html
<xf:instance id="myDetails">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$detailDocument" />
</xf:instance>
```

It works fine and the instance value is set correctly. However, later I need to update the value of this instance with another document. I tried something like follows but didn't work:

```html
 <xf:setvalue ref="instance('myDetails')"><xsl:copy-of select="$updatedDetailDocument" /></xf:setvalue>
```

This just makes the instance empty even though I know updatedDetailDocument is not empty. Does xf:setvalue even support setting instances ? Or is there any other way of doing the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xf:setvalue>` is used to set text within an XML attribute or XML element. In order to set a tree or subtree of XML, you would need the [`<xf:insert>` action](https://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#action-insert) instead.

You don't say how you are getting `$updatedDetailDocument`, but since this is dynamic you probably need to retrieve that updated document using [`<xf:submission>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#submit), in which case you won't need `<xf:insert>` because `<xf:submission>` can directly update your instance with `replace="instance"`.

Comment: Thanks. I can use xf:insert followed by a xf:delete to delete the old node.